# PHP echo in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have this code:

```
 document.getElementById('root').style.left = '<?php echo $page_position[$info["os"]][$info["browser"]][0]; ?>';
 document.getElementById('root').style.top = '<?php echo $page_position[$info["os"]][$info["browser"]][1]; ?>';
```

Why won't this work like this?

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

```
<?php echo $page_position[$info["os"]][$info["browser"]][1]; ?>
```

echoed "top:300px;"

Sorry guys, very stupid error of mine :/

Comment: Can you post more of the script?

Comment: Is the echoing in the code above correct? I think that's the problem... The normal php echo outside the js part works...

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work?" What are your expected results, what is actually happening, and how are you running it?

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump` of your variables to make sure the contents are all correct?

Comment: The variables echo as usual outside the js tag... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Things to check:

1. Check to make sure those variables are available. `print_r($info)` will help you out.
2. Make sure that the code is actually being filled with those variables (symptom of #1). View source and check that they are there.
3. Ensure you don't have any JavaScript errors preceding your code. Open your console (like Firebug) and check to make sure you don't.
4. Ensure that a `root` element exists. Again, use your console.

My money goes on #3, you probably have a JavaScript error somewhere that is stopping execution of the script.

Answer (score 3):

If you put it in a `.js` file, it won't work because it must be in a page that is parsed for PHP (`.php`).

Comment: Please post more of the script.